# Java: XML canonicalization

Tags: java, xml, canonicalization

What's the easiest way to make a canonical form of a XML file in Java? Do you have some done code for that? I've found several links on the net, like [this](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/XML/xom/nu/xom/canonical/Canonicalizer.java.htm), [this](http://koders.com/java/fid80EBAB24CF0FD266C7AE01964FD77EAFA9430C46.aspx?s=base64#L34), and [this](http://jcs.mobile-utopia.com/jcs/11015_Canonicalizer.java), but I can't make it to work :/

Thanks,

Ivan

EDIT: I used the canonicalizer that was proposed down there, but I get strange results. To be more precize, this method doesn't delete white spaces between elements... This is what I get:

```
<Metric xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/wsla" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" name="total_memory_consumption_metric" type="double" unit="Mbit" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.ibm.com/wsla WSLA.xsd">                        <Source>ServiceProvider</Source>                        <MeasurementDirective resultType="double" xsi:type="StatusRequest">                              <RequestURI> ***unused*** </RequestURI>                        </MeasurementDirective>                  </Metric>
```

Comment: Same problem, did you manage to solve it by now ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The [Canonicalizer](http://santuario.apache.org/Java/api/org/apache/xml/security/c14n/Canonicalizer.html) class at [Apache XML Security project](http://santuario.apache.org/).

Initialize the library.

```
org.apache.xml.security.Init.init();
```

Convert your XML.

```
Canonicalizer canon = Canonicalizer.getInstance(Canonicalizer.ALGO_ID_C14N_OMIT_COMMENTS);
byte canonXmlBytes[] = canon.canonicalize(yourXmlBytes);
String canonXmlString = new String(canonXmlBytes);
```

Comment: To anyone who hasn't worked with the Apache XML Security library before, you must initialize the library using the static method "org.apache.xml.security.Init.init();" before invoking any code from that library, or you'll get an error.

Comment: The point @Stew makes is quite important.  It should really be part of the answer itself.

Comment: I find this solution doesn't work on emoji character which becomes "??" after canonicalized.

Comment: @Stew I added your library initialization to the original answer. Better late than never :)

Answer (score 2):

Another option is [nu.xom.canonical.Canonicalizer](http://www.xom.nu/apidocs/nu/xom/canonical/Canonicalizer.html) if you're using XOM, or if you don't otherwise have a need for Apache XML Security.

Comment: This is the better option. In my case I called Serializer first and then directed the result to Canonicalizer. The result was a more readable canonical XML.