# Could anyone verify the correctness of getting a md5 hash using this method?

Tags: java, md5, hash

```
        MessageDigest m=MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        if(nodeName!=null) sb.append(nodeName);
        if(nodeParentName!=null) sb.append(nodeParentName);
        if(nodeParentFieldName!=null) sb.append(nodeParentFieldName);
        if(nodeRelationName!=null) sb.append(nodeRelationName);
        if(nodeViewName!=null) sb.append(nodeViewName);
        if(treeName!=null) sb.append(treeName);
        if(nodeValue!=null && nodeValue.trim().length()>0) sb.append(nodeValue);
        if(considerParentHash) sb.append(parentHash);
        m.update(sb.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"),0,sb.toString().length());
        BigInteger i = new BigInteger(1,m.digest());
        hash = String.format("%1$032X", i);
```

The idea behind these lines of code is that we append all the values of a class/model into a StringBuilder and then return the padded hash of that (the Java implementation returns md5 hashes that are lenght 30 or 31, so the last line formats the hash to be padded with 0s).

I can verify that this works, but I have a feeling it fails at one point (our application fails and I believe this to be the probable cause).

Can anyone see a reason why this wouldn't work? Are there any workarounds to make this code less prone to errors (e.g. removing the need for the strings to be UTF-8).

Comment: UTF-8 strings can contain multibyte characters, in which (as the name suggests) a character spans more than one byte. So if any of your data fields will possibly ever contain characters which would be multibyte in a UTF-8 representation, then using length() would be incorrect, because length() counts characters, not bytes. But to be honest, I'm not sure if this actually matters - does it really matter if the byte array used to create the hash is slightly truncated? It would matter if the hash were created by different code somewhere else, certainly. But why would you have 2 routines for that?

Comment: how does your application fail? please provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) demonstrating the fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few weird things in your code.

UTF-8 encoding of a character may use more than one byte. So you should not use the *string* length as final parameter to the `update()` call, but the length of the array of bytes that `getBytes()` actually returned. As suggested by Paŭlo, use the `update()` method which takes a single `byte[]` as parameter.

The output of MD5 is a sequence of 16 bytes with quite arbitrary values. If you interpret it as an integer (that's what you do with your call to `BigInteger()`), then you will get a numerical value which will be smaller than *2<sup>160</sup>*, possibly much smaller. When converted back to hexadecimal digits, you may get 32, 31, 30... or *less than 30* characters. Your usage of the the `"%032X"` format string left-pads with enough zeros, so your code works, but it is kind of indirect (the output of MD5 has never been an integer to begin with).

You assemble the hash input elements with raw concatenation. This may induce issues. For instance, if `modeName` is "`foo`" and `modeParentName` is "`barqux`", then the MD5 input will begin with (the UTF-8 encoding of) "`foobarqux`". If `modeName` is "`foobar`" and `modeParentName` is "`qux`", then the MD5 input will *also* begin with "`foobarqux`". You do not tell why you want to use a hash function, but usually, when one uses a hash function, it is to have a unique trace of some piece of data; two distinct data elements should yield distinct hash inputs.

When handling `nodeValue`, you call `trim()`, which means that this string could begin and/or end with whitespace, and you do not want to include that whitespace into the hash input -- but you *do* include it, since you append `nodeValue` and not `nodeValue.trim()`.

If what you are trying to do has any relation to security then you should not use MD5, which is cryptographically broken. Use SHA-256 instead.

Hashing an XML element is normally done through canonicalization (which handles whitespace, attribute order, text representation, and so on). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117610/java-xml-canonicalization) on the topic of canonicalizing XML data with Java.

Answer (score 0):

One possible problem is here:

```
m.update(sb.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"),0,sb.toString().length());
```

As said by Robing Green, the `UTF-8` encoding can produce a `byte[]` which is longer than your original string (it will do this exactly when the String contains non-ASCII characters). In this case, you are only hashing the start of your String.

Better write it like this:

```
m.update(sb.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

Of course, this would not cause an exception, simply another hash than would be produced otherwise, if you have non-ASCII-characters in your string. You should try to brew your failure down to an SSCCE, like lesmana recommended.