# Sort xml attributes alphabetically

Tags: xml

I'd like

```
<node a="2" d="1" c="2">
```

to be converted to

```
<node a="2" c="2" d="1">
```

Can you propose some solution with less effort?

Comment: Might help to explain why you care about the order of the attributes. Any XML parsing code should accept attributes in any order.

Comment: Why?!? There is no order in the attributes of an XML node - nor should the "order" matter in any way....

Comment: The solution depends entirely on the programming language, what library you're using, etc. And as marc_s mentioned, this is for aesthetics and possibly better human-readability only.

Comment: Well, I've got java code that load and saves xml data. I've migrated from digester to Jaxb. I want to make sure that everything is ok.

Comment: I have an example where the order matters. I have XML data stored in a Git repository.  The library that creates it puts the attributes in random order. This means that a `git diff` results in hundreds of lines with "changes" and so I cannot tell how the data differ between the two files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an XML canonicalization library. XML canonical form requires the attributes to be in alphabetical order (so that two documents can be compared for equivalence by comparing them at the byte level).

Comment: Not without knowing anything about your environment and constraints, no.

Comment: Well, I run Windows 7 or Linux. I use java 1.6. So?

Comment: Then you can google as easily as I can: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117610/java-xml-canonicalization