# hash for input stream vs character stream

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, hash

We are developing a Java based application and use Hibernate for DAO. I have an XML data store as Clob in the database. With Hibernate Clob object and parse it into a String. Then I HASH(SHA-256) it.

The Clob object has 2 method.

1. `getAsciiStream()` returns `InputSteam`
2. `getCharacterStream()`
   returns `Reader`

The parser parses the `InputStream` or `Reader` into a exactly same String. However the Hash generated from each of them are different. Why?

Context: We currently are using `getAsciiStream()` and it limits many special characters. So we have to change it `getCharacterStream()`. However, our application (it does hash comparison for business reasons)  and customers will be affected with the change.

```
Example XML:
<application>
    <header>
        <subtitle>WHAT EVER</subtitle>
        <page_header>WHAT EVER</page_header>
    </header>
    <form>
        <application_form_name>WHAT EVER</application_form_name>
        <section>
            <section_name>WHAT EVER</section_name>
            <question>
                <question_text>How is this applicant to something?</question_text>
                <answer>WHAT EVER</answer>
            </question>
            <question>
                <question_text>What is something?</question_text>
                <answer>WHAT EVER</answer>
            </question>
            <question>
                <question_text>Type of Customer</question_text>
                <answer>Organization</answer>
            </question>
            <question>
                <question_text>Full legal name of the applicant:</question_text>
                <answer/>
            </question>
            <question>
                <question_text>Legal Name</question_text>
                <answer>WHAT EVER</answer>
            </question>
            <question>
                <question_text>WHAT EVER</question_text>
                <answer/>
            </question>
            <question>
                <question_text>WHAT EVER</question_text>
                <answer/>
            </question>
            <question>
                <question_text>WHAT EVER</question_text>
                <answer/>
            </question>
            <question>
                <question_text>WHAT EVER</question_text>
                <answer/>
            </question>
        </section>
    </form>
</application>
```

Comment: Possibly: Different encodings are being used and you didn't see slight differences in the resulting String objects.

Comment: Hashing is done on bytes, not on characters.  If you're hashing a `String`, it's getting converted back into bytes -- possibly in some different way than the way it was originally converted from.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK getAsciiStream is deprecated

Also please provide your hash-calculation code for both (getAsciiStream/getCharacterStream) versions - the whole part - how do You read from DB and how do you feed data to MessageDigest. It's much more informative than your XML sample.

Btw. Since XML has non-significant white spaces where are special (non-significant white space   ignoring) way how to calculate message digest on XML Data:

- [Canonical XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_XML)
- [W3C SPEC](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-c14n)
- [Java XML Digital Signature API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/xmldsig/XMLDigitalSignature.html)
- [Java XML Canonicalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117610/java-xml-canonicalization)

Btw. You still doing it wrong. You can store ANY characters in XML with plain latin1 encoding just using entities. So you can keep you XML reading code AS-IS but change your XML-to-String code (specify latin1 encoding for XmlWriter).